# Parsing XML file with FSharp XMLProvider

Tags: xml, f#, f#-data

I have an XML file `sample.xml` that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
            http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.8.xsd">

    <changeSet author="x" id="y">
        <sqlFile
            endDelimiter="\nGO"
            path="ChangeSetScripts/1.sql"
            relativeToChangelogFile="true"
            splitStatements="true"
            stripComments="false"/>
        <rollback>
            <sqlFile path="ChangeSetScripts/1_rollback.sql" />
        </rollback>
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet author="a" id="b">
        <sqlFile
            endDelimiter="\nGO"
            path="ChangeSetScripts/2.sql"
            relativeToChangelogFile="true"
            splitStatements="true"
            stripComments="false"/>
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet author="p" id="q">
        <sqlFile
            endDelimiter="\nGO"
            path="ChangeSetScripts/3.sql"
            relativeToChangelogFile="true"
            splitStatements="true"
            stripComments="false"/>
        <rollback>
            <sqlFile path="ChangeSetScripts/5_rollback.sql" />
        </rollback>
    </changeSet>
    
    ...

</databaseChangeLog>
```

I want to add a new `changeSet` entry to this file using F# XMLProvider. There may or may not be a rollback file as apparent from the sample. How can I do this? (`id`, `author` and `path` will be passed as argument)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first question is whether you want to mutate the existing document or create a new one.
The types generated by the XML provider are immutable, so it works better if you create a new document, however the underlying `XElement` objects can be mutated so you could potentially do that too.

To create a new modified document, you would just use the provided types to construct a new `DatabaseChangeLog` value with new `ChangeSet` list:

```
type Log = XmlProvider<"c:/temp/sample.xml">
let doc = Log.Load("c:/temp/sample.xml")

// Create a new changeset and specify all required values
let changeSet =
  Log.ChangeSet("New Author", "new_id", 
    Log.SqlFile("/", "c:/path", false, false, false), None)

// Create a new file with the new changeset
let changeSets = Array.append doc.ChangeSets [| changeSet |]  
let newFile = Log.DatabaseChangeLog(doc.SchemaLocation, doc.ChangeSets)

// To get the new XML document as a string before saving it
newFile.ToString()
```

**EDIT:** If you wanted to add the new `changeSet` to the existing document, the way to do this would be to do something like this:

```
doc.XElement.Add(changeSet.XElement)
doc.XElement.Save("sample.xml")
```

Comment: If I want to append to the existing file, how can I do that?

Comment: Also, how can I escape the special characters?

Comment: I added an example of how to mutate the document. Regarding the special characters - can you be more specific?

Comment: I put the endDelimiter inside a variable and forgot to escape the newline character. The change set entry is appended correctly, but the format is not preserved (the new entry is entirely on its own line, not following the structure in the given file). Is there any way to preserve the structure as it is given in the file?

Comment: You can see the difference here: https://imgur.com/Mecc9JI

Comment: Any way to make the structure of the last entry like the one before it (in the image)?

Comment: Basically, the whitespace structure is not preserved

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to do this - you could probably clone an existing node and mutate that, but that may just be easier to do without the XML type provider.

Comment: Any hints on what to use other than XML type provider to achieve this?